# VHDL : Library required

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, ieee-754

I generated random float numbers (decimal format) and saved them in a text file. and I made a code for read that file in VHDL. Now I want to convert these floating point number into IEEE Format (32 bir or 64 bit). Is there any library available which I could use for my work. 
or there is any code in VHDL.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a VHDL floating-point package:

http://vhdl.org/fphdl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a float number to IEEE 754 (e.g. 1.0 -> 0x3F800000) through pure software scripts:

1. matlab script:

   Matlab program to convert a real number to a number in IEEE 754 floating point format
   http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~ismail/courses/c92/fpu/
2. lisp script: http://common-lisp.net/project/ieee-floats/

   using **encode-float32** defined in ieee-floats, there is a quick conversion.

   ```
   (defun fix2float (fp)
        (format t "~%~x~T~x" fp (ieee-floats:encode-float32 fp)))
    (fix2float 1.1)
   ```

As for hardware library, Vfloat(Xiaojun Wang, 2010) is worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use random numbers in VHDL, why not use the UNIFORM function from the *math_real* library? Uniform is your function, the usage is explained in the definition

```
procedure UNIFORM (variable Seed1,Seed2:inout integer; variable X:out real);
    -- returns a pseudo-random number with uniform distribution in the 
    -- interval (0.0, 1.0).
    -- Before the first call to UNIFORM, the seed values (Seed1, Seed2) must
    -- be initialized to values in the range [1, 2147483562] and 
    -- [1, 2147483398] respectively.  The seed values are modified after 
    -- each call to UNIFORM.
    -- This random number generator is portable for 32-bit computers, and
    -- it has period ~2.30584*(10**18) for each set of seed values.
    --
    -- For VHDL-1992, the seeds will be global variables, functions to 
    -- initialize their values (INIT_SEED) will be provided, and the UNIFORM
    -- procedure call will be modified accordingly.
```

If that is not what you need, use the *std_textio* package to read the data:

```
procedure READ(L:inout LINE; VALUE: out real; GOOD : out BOOLEAN);
procedure READ(L:inout LINE; VALUE: out real);
```

Comment: Thanks BennyBarns. the problem is not about reading the file. I did this already. Now I want to convert these floating point number into IEEE format. should I use the library?

Comment: Then you should be more precise rather than vote down an answer. So you mean IEEE 754? I thought you were talking about ieee.std_logic_1164! In that case you will be using some kind of blockset for 754 operations, which should provide conversions... I can remember that synplicity sure does

Comment: Let say I generated a text file in which floating numbers are like this way
1.9832, 
0.211, 
-1.12 

I made code in VHDL which can read this. Now I want to convert these numbers into IEEE-754 (32 bit format). For this, which library I need.